# get_terms(get_the_ID) shows WP_Error

Tags: wordpress, tags, taxonomy

Im trying to display my custom taxonomy tags from inside the post but it returns NULL or WP_Error

```php
var_dump(get_terms(get_the_ID()));

// Returns this
object(WP_Error)#6268 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["invalid_taxonomy"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(20) "Taxonomia inválida." } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }
```

Why does this say its and invalid taxonomy?

Comment: You need to pass the taxonomy but you are passing the post ID. Try var_dump(get_terms('post_tag'));

Comment: returns empty array

Comment: Because you haven't added any post tags. Try creating a few post tags and run the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong function, `get_terms` will return list of the terms in the taxonomy. If you want to list the terms of the post containing the custom taxonomy, you need to use the `get_the_terms`

```
var_dump( get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'your-custom-taxonomy');
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/